# Data schema to store heterogeneous data in parquet files inside HDFS

Tags: database, hdfs, parquet

We want to store data like:

```
{"event":"click", "click_url":..., ...},
{"event":"view","view_item":...., ...}
```

Each event (click/view/load/hit....) have different fields.

Currently, we group all kind of events in same parquet files, this end up with 90 fields, most the time null (sparse data because for a view event, all click_* fields are null).

As we plan to add more and more events, this is not scalable (I cant image a parquet file with more than 128 columns!).

We use partition already: `year=2018/month=8/day=20`, a single Hive table and Apache Spark to query.

What could be the best architecture (maybe a partition by event with a Hive table associated) to fit this?

Comment: I've worked with 20,000+ parquet columns before and it worked well.  What problem are you having with number of columns?

Comment: 20K columns really? The problem is I see performance is better with a parquet file with 10 columns than 200 (with Hive + Spark). I even cant cache (Spark in memory) if too many columns (looks like Spark doesnt like sparse data. Also, how can you work with 20K columns (do you have a special toolchain)?

Comment: 20k columns, billions of rows.  Just need a big enough cluster :)  No special toolchain, but you do have to stop typing column names.  I have metadata that says what the columns exactly were, but the schema would be type1-N, othertype1-N, etc.  Then I can select a type like `manyColumnsDF.select( [col for col in manyColumnsDF.columns if col.startswith("type")] )`  or do other tricks based on working with dynamic lists of columns.  If you ask a new question for this I'll give an answer :)

Comment: Just noticed you mention Hive+Spark.  is it possible you are having a Hive issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the union of the different schemas like you are already doing. Storing "sparse" or "wide" data (large number of columns in the table but low number of columns in individual records) is in fact one area where Parquet excels. A few excerpts from articles that mention this:

From [Dremel made simple with Parquet](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2013/dremel-made-simple-with-parquet.html):

> A sparse column with a lot of null values will compress to almost nothing

From [Parquet: Columnar Storage for Hadoop Data](https://techblog.appnexus.com/parquet-columnar-storage-for-hadoop-data-726d6dd36185):

> Parquet really excels when the query is on sparse data or low cardinality in column selection.

and

> It is especially good for queries which read particular columns from a “wide” (with many columns) table, since only needed columns are read and IO is minimized."

You will probably probably want to mention specific columns in your queries instead of doing a `SELECT *` to take advantage of this.

Comment: Many thanks for these quotes! So it's a good practice to have a single "sparse big" file, rather than many "dense small" files (especially for an analytics data warehouse).

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to call it a good practice, but Parquet tolerates this practice relatively well and many people do it. On the other hand, you may have other maintainability issues, like the mental effort of comprehending the data structure, complicated queries and no way to delete data for a specific event type (other than rewriting the files).

Comment: One more thing: A Hive table consists of multiple files, so it's not a question of a single sparse _file_ vs. multiple dense _files_, but of a single sparse _table_ vs. multiple dense _tables_. In fact, the number and the size of those files is much more critical to performance than the number of columns in them. For example, if you insert records one-by-one, an individual file will be created for each record and performance will suffer.

Comment: we use a good toolchain that create SQL queries (create table, update columns and ETL) from elasticsearch mappings, and versionize YAML schema that reflect all data schema. For now, we create a Parquet file every day (partitioned by year/month/day), I could try to partition by "event" too and bench it.